# Json data in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have json data in following format. I want to access data from json and print it on html table.

```
[region:
    [name:"",
     code:""IntradayBalance:{   currency:,Time:,Balance:    }....
    ],
    acccountcurrencyBalance:[{ currency: ,Time: ,Balance: , 
        },...],]
    [country :  
        [name:"",
         code:""
        IntradayBalance:
        {   
            currency:
            Time:
            Balance:

        }....
    ],      
    acccountcurrencyBalance:[
    {
            currency:
            Time:
            Balance:    
    },...], 
]
```

i Want to access data from "acccountcurrencyBalance", but i m only able to print data "region name"
code i am doing in my controller is as.

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(data){$scope.response=data}
```

and my html code is

```
<ul ng-repeat="a in response">
    <li>{{a.region}}</li>
</ul>
<ul ng-repeat="a in response.accountcurrencyBalance">
    <li>{{a.accountcurrencyBalance.time}}</li>
</ul>
```

But its only able to show Region Name not the data from account currency balance. Any one can please help.

Comment: Unclear as you have not provided much of the json. It appears as if your acccountcurrencyBalance is in your region section of the Json, which I imagine is not correct. Use console.log(response) and look at the chrome developer tools (f12) console to debug this this

Comment: yes its in region section and country section also has it's own account currency balance.

Comment: I've had a poke at an answer based on what I can see. If you provide more information, such as what a.region returns, then I am more likely to be able to help

Comment: Shubham please give detail json structure

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't have [valid json](http://jsonlint.com/).

Example of valid json:

```
{"data": [{"id": 1, "name": "name1"}]}
```

Secondly, you have to access *data.data* in success function. Read [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs:

```
$http.get('data.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.response=response.data; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have just given a format of my json data thats why i have not followed syntax. it is valid json. and second $scope.response=data also works.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<ul ng-repeat="a in response">
    <li>{{a.region.acccountcurrencyBalance}}</li>
</ul>
```